# How can I reset touchIDLockout after successful login?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I've successfully implemented Touch ID on an iOS app. However I'm trying to handle the error case when there are too many failed Touch ID attempts by the user.

I'm able to let the user close the Touch ID dialog and login via username/password text entry, but upon logging back out and trying to use Touch ID once again, `localAuthContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError)` returns false with error: `LAError.touchIDLockout`.

Is there some function/boolean I can use to reset the lockout after the user successfully logins in with their username and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lockout appears to be enforced by the OS. This is probably to prevent userland apps from circumventing security policies (malicious or not).

From **[Apple's iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf)** (pg. 7):

> ...The passcode can always be used instead of Touch ID, and it’s still
>   required under the following circumstances:
>
> • The device has just been turned on or restarted.
>
> • The device hasn’t been unlocked for more than 48 hours.
>
> • The passcode hasn’t been used to unlock the device in the
>   last 156 hours (six and a half days) and Touch ID has not unlocked the
>   device in the last 4 hours.
>
> • The device has received a remote lock command.
>
> • **After five unsuccessful attempts to match a fingerprint.**
>
> • When setting up or enrolling new fingers with Touch ID.

Bold formatting is mine.

Touch ID seems to be offered as a convenient alternative for authentication for your app. Since you have a fallback method of authenticating your users, perhaps you could utilize it before there are five unsuccessful Touch ID attempts (and of course if Touch ID is not available).

**EDIT:**

I found some documentation in the `LAError.h` file which provides some context for what `touchIDLockout` means. It does not explicitly state how many attempts result in a lockout, however it does state that the passcode is now required. This lines up with the above information from Apple's iOS Security Guide.

Based on this developer facing information, I would conclude that resetting a lockout that resulted from a number of unsuccessful Touch ID attempts is something that cannot be done by a developer.

Hope this additional information helps.

Comment: Correct, it's a convenience alternative. Before I enable Touch ID on my login page, the user must first correctly authenticate with a username and password. Subsequent logins will be offered the Touch ID method. Your link above is sort of unrelated since it deals with unlocking the OS of device, and not developer usage.

Comment: The lockout can be reset by locking the phone itself and then unlocking it with your passcode (since Touch ID at the OS level will also be disabled).